# Dynamic SQL result into temp table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to insert a dynamic SQL result into a temp table like this which did not work.

```
DECLARE @dq AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp1;

SET @dq = N'SELECT col1 INTO #temp1 FROM tbl;';

EXEC sp_executesql @dq;

SELECT * FROM #temp1;
```

It is generating the following error

> Invalid object name '#temp1'

Comment: A temporary table created into a deferred scope is *dropped* at the end of that scope, which means that when you try to `SELECT` from it it's already been implicitly dropped. You'll need to `CREATE` the table *outside* of the deferred scope and use `INSERT INTO ... EXEC` syntax or `INSERT INTO... SELECT` *inside* the deffered batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem.
Just change the datatype of "col1" to whatever datatype you expect to get from "tbl".

```
DECLARE @dq AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

Create table #temp1 (col1 INT)

SET @dq = N'insert into #temp1 SELECT col1 FROM tbl;';

EXEC sp_executesql @dq;

SELECT * FROM #temp1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global temp-table, by having two hash-signs in front instead of one, like so:

```sql
DECLARE @dq AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##temp1;

SET @dq = N'SELECT col1 INTO ##temp1 FROM tbl;';

EXEC sp_executesql @dq;

SELECT * FROM ##temp1;
```

But you need to be aware that this temp table is then visible to all users, and consider concurrency issues if you're running multiple instances of this query in overlapping times or separate sessions.